# PHP Dynamic JavaScript Values

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, module

I have recently Created a sliding module for Joomla, and I have a JavaScript file with the following parameters :

```
scrollbar: true,
snapToChildren: true,
desktopClickDrag: true,
scrollbarMargin: '5px 40px 0 40px',
scrollbarBorderRadius: 0,
scrollbarHeight: '2px',
```

I just want to know how to make these values dynamic so that they can pull in the values from PHP, so that it can be adjusted in the back-end parameters in joomla.

Any Help appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) ??

Comment: for getting value in js file you have to use the ajax for it or , put above all parameter in one function , and at php side call the function, hope it will help

Comment: i would never mix php with javascript, instead use data-attribute or hidden elements to store and change the value from php. and fetch it via jQuery.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar: Why is that any better?

Comment: i like to keep sperate files for js. and js file does not recognize php. further on javascript is meant to fetch the value of client side, hence IMO it should not interfere with server side, AJAX was used for the purpose of communication with server side. why not use AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that in your php file :

```
scrollbarHeight: '<?php echo $yourvalue; ?>px',
```

and so on for every value you want to update dynamically.

Comment: Also perfect, once i embedded the javascript into my php.. THANK YOU :D

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the values from the php code when the page loads. You might have something like:

```
echo 'var some_javascript_value = '.$the_PHP_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm recommending you to look into a free joomla extension structure, you can lear from it a lot. [Here](http://offlajn.com/blog/entry/2012/03/20/free-glassy-menu-module.html) is a free extension that we made about a month ago, you can take a peek on the code if you like.

What you are looking for, is connecting the backend parameters with the frontend so you can make your extension more user friendly.

I would do something like this (joomla 1.5 example):

Make the module xml file, because it contains the module settings you see on the backend. In your case it would be something like:

```
<param name="scrollbar" type="list" default="1">
            <option value="true">Yes</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
</param>
```

This is one parameter for the scrollbar setting. The corresponding code for the frontend would be:

```
...    
scrollbar: <?php echo $params->get('scrollbar', "true"); ?>,
...
```

This makes you scrollbar parameter dinamic. If the user chooses Yes then the value will be true and false otherwise.

Comment: Perfect, once i embedded the javascript into my php file it works :D... thanks so much..